# User-Inputted hex into a hex array

Tags: c++, hex

What I need to do is the following.

```
const char *arrayHex[4];
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{    
cin << uHex;
arrayHex[i] = uHex;
}
```

But I need the members of arrayHex to be hex escaped with \x. How might I go about doing that?

This was really vaguely worded, edit to fix(hopefully)

If the input is 41, I want the result when printed to be "A", as if the value was "\x41"

Comment: your loop is wrong! your array is only 4 elements but you loop from i =0 to 4, which is 5.

Comment: ... and `arrayHex` is an array of char pointers. Is `uHex` a pointer as well, or did you mean to create an array of chars? If the latter, the `const` should be omitted, since you're assigning to that array.

Comment: @Michael Post an example input and output?

Comment: Try [`boost::algorithm::hex()`](http://www.boost.org/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/Misc/hex.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // for strtol()
#include <cstdio>  // for printf()
#define countof(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

int main()
{
    std::string uHex;
    long arrayValues[4];
    for( int i = 0; i < countof(arrayValues); ++i )
    {
        std::cin >> uHex;
        char* end;
        arrayValues[i] = std::strtol(uHex.c_str(), &end, 16);
        // At this point, we expect end to be pointing at the '\0'
        // (the C-string nul terminator).  If it's not, then we have
        // invalid chars in our input, and arrayValues[i] is bogus.
        if (*end != '\0')
        {
           std::cout << "Invalid characters: \"" << uHex << "\" (please try again)\n";
           --i; // compensate for the ++i above to re-try this again
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < countof(arrayValues); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i << " --> " << arrayValues[i] << " --> "
                  << static_cast<char>(arrayValues[i]) << '\n';
//      std::printf("%d --> %d --> %c\n", i, arrayValues[i], arrayValues[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm printing the exact same output both ways:  with cout or with printf().  Personally I like printf() not because that's what I learned first, but because printf() formatted output is significantly more expressive (for MOST built-in types) with less verbosity than cout, even though cout is more flexible because you can create cout output functions for user-defined types.  But if your compiler doesn't do printf()/scanf() format-parameter type checking (GCC does, if you enable it), then you can easily create some interesting & confusing output with mismatched types, and create nice non-deterministic SEGV generators quite easily by specifying less args than your format string indicates.

Comment: Not exactly what I need, I need it to be hex escaped. For example, user inputs 41, when I print the value that 41 was saved to it prints "A"

Comment: @Michael - OK, I changed it to do what I think you want it to do now.  In case you don't realize it, a number can (and really should, in most cases) be stored in a computer in pure numeric (binary) form, such as `int`, `long`, `unsigned int`, etc.  A number stored as a std::string or as a char[] array (directly or via char*) is not really a number, as far as the CPU is concerned.  The CPU can't directly add/subtract/multiply/divide/etc a number stored as character digits.  In its pure numeric (binary) form, the number isn't "decimal" or "hexadecimal", it's simply pure numeric.

Comment: ...A numeric value can only be REPRESENTED (i.e. printed) in "decimal" or "hexadecimal" form.  If you're STORING a number in "decimal" or "hex" form (i.e. in a std::string or char[]/char*), then you're not storing it in a form that the CPU understands to be a number.  HOWEVER, sometimes other storage forms are used (including std::string/char[]/char*) for domain-specific reasons, including high-precision scientific/engineering calculations, databases, etc.

Comment: ...In your case, you want to input a numeric value (in hex form), and print out its ASCII character representation.  So I'm converting the value that was entered (in character form) into a pure numeric integer (`long`).  When I print it, for cout, I cast it as a `char` so that cout prints the ASCII character representation of that numeric value.